# Error 400 forbidden on Upload image in South Korea

Tags: imgur

I have been using imgur API for almost a year and it was working pretty well until 2days ago.

Suddenly all my users from south korea can't upload any images.

I'm doing a simple POST request on

```
https://api.imgur.com/3/image
```

and got the following answer

```
    data    Object { error: "These actions are forbidden." }
    error   "These actions are forbidden."
    success false
    status  400
```

I have tried different size of image (< 1mb or > 1mb), format (jpg, png etc ...) and it's not working only for people with a Korean IP, I actually tried it with a VPN for having a Korean IP and it's not working. If I turn off the VPN and try to upload without refreshing the page it's working.

My code haven't change since few months so I don't know why it would stop working suddenly

Is there something wrong with Korea or a change in the policy ? I can't see any.